# Is it necessary to book a bus ticket from Morskoe to Nida in advance?

Tags: tickets, buses, russia, lithuania

I will be travelling from Morskoe (in Russia) to Nida (in Lithuania) on a weekend this July, certainly in high season. The bus I intend to take is [route 384](http://vokzal39.ru/bus-klaypeda.html).

Is it necessary to book a ticket in advance, or I can get on it at the spot according to the timetable and pay cash to the bus driver? I can't enter Morskoe as the origin in the [ticket booking website](http://avtovokzal39.ru/menu_pokup5.htm).

Comment: I have just found out I can book a ticket form the Lithuanian website https://www.autobusubilietai.lt/index.php?lang=0&cl=select&fnc=searchByStopId&travel_from=2730-2,2730-1&travel_to=3015-1 , is it necessary to do so?

Comment: Can you please add the country or countries, I have tried to find information for you online but I did get a few options for cities with these names.

Answer (score 3):

It should be a 2x15 minutes ride so I assume you should be able to do that even if all seats are occuppied.

Then again, for 1 euro, why not just buy this ticket and forget? I mean, even if you waste one euro, is it worth to continue pondering?

Comment: I bought the bus ticket saying 18:40 and waited at the bus stop on the main road starting from 18:20, but the bus didn't appear and I ended in trouble.

Comment: @MichaelTsang sorry to hear that :(